# How to import JSON object with functions inside?

Tags: javascript, json, js.class

Good day,

I am playing with **JS.Class** right now and I'm making a text-based game. For now, it is executed in a browser but eventually,
it will be executed in a Node.js environment managing sockets and ANSI colors supports for players using a telnet-like client.

I have created a few classes and one of them define Characters (which is either a real player or an in-game character).

For a real player, the code to create a new one looks like this: `new Character( "userId", { /* player's options/settings/parameters here*/ }, socket );`

Example:

```
new Character( "000001", {
    "Name" : "Cybrix",
    "Zone" : "000001-000003",
    "Stealth" : false,
    "Fighting" : false,
    "Blind" : false,
    "Sleeping" : false
}, socket );
```

More than often, the in-game characters should have differents and uniques methods that I use to simulate an event-like behavior.

Example:

```
new Character( "000001", {
    "Name" : "Large Dragon Boss",
    "Zone" : "000001-000003",
    "Stealth" : false,
    "Fighting" : false,
    "Blind" : false,
    "Sleeping" : true,
    "onArrive" : function( target ) {
        /* do something unique to this character. Eg: attack target */
    }
}, undefined );
```

The question:

I would like to find an efficient way to load all the "uniques" in-game characters on demand (which happens usually when a new area is loaded).
that will support functions. I really thought about using AJAX but that would be invalid JSON format.

Any tips on how to achieve this or what should I change in my "game" design to achieve this?

I, for sure, need a solution that will both work in my **browser** and can be ported nicely to **Node.js**.

Thank you!

(PS: Sorry for my very specific problem that might not help anyone else)
(PS 2: I don't know how what question to use in the Title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can these characters be split into types of characters.  You could have your character types inherit from `Character` and each implement their own `onArrive` method.  Something like:

```
function Dude(){};
Dude.prototype = new Character         // inherit from character
Dude.prototoype.onArrive = function(){
  // do some stuff
}
```

And so on.

You can't have a function defined in your JSON returned from a server, nor do you want to.  That would be too tightly coupled.  Just define object prototypes that inherit and create character types that have the appropriate 'features' (or behaviour)

*Additional*

I'm a bit confused as to what you're looking for, but let me take another stab.  IF you have some data being exchanged between a few servers, (character data) you want to be able to instantiate objects of a certain type.  Assuming this data knows its type (ie add this as a property to the character JSON) then you can instantiate an object of any type.  Using the above prototype declarations, you can create as many types of Character that you want.  You could then instantiate this type through some factory method.  For instance

```
var Factory = {
  new: function(attrs){
    return new classes[attrs.type](attrs);
  }
};

var classes = {
  dude: Dude,
  another: Another,
  blah: Lah,
};
```

Assuming that you've defined Dude, Another, Lah as other prototypes of `Character` and they each implement some `onAdd` method (or just use the default defined in `Character`.  Then you can use it like so:

```
character = Factory.new({
  type: 'dude',
  "Name" : "Cybrix",
  "Zone" : "000001-000003",
  "Stealth" : false,
  "Fighting" : false,
  "Blind" : false,
  "Sleeping" : false
});

character.onAdd();
```

Comment: How can implement that solution "on-Demand"? Because unless I'm told otherwise, I doubt having all the prototypes of every single and uniques mobiles (in-game characters) already loaded is very efficient.

Comment: The JSON objects will passes server-to-server. The real player won't see anything and he can't affect it at all.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused as to what you're looking for.  what do you mean by `prototypes of every single and uniques mobiles`.  These are object no?  They should just inherit their behaviour from a particular prototype depending on their type.  Not sure what you mean by `on demand`.  When you instantiate a new object, it doesn't actually contain the `onArrive` method, it gets it from the prototype, so 100 of these objects still just have 1 method `onArrive`.  That's the whole point

Comment: Again though, JSON is a data interchange format, not behaviour.  Share your prototype declarations amongst servers, and they'll all use the same behaviour

Comment: @brad, let's say I have an area containing 206 in-game character. A few of them (maybe not all of them) must have the "onArrive" method. Some of them will simply greets the player, some of them will attack the player or do anything else unique to their duties when that method is called. Those 206 Character should not be loaded unless a real player is standing inside that area. That is what I meant by on-Demand. Also, that is why I thought about using JSON (between my Node.js server and, I dont know, maybe a file named loadCharacter.php?charId=*** also hosted on server).Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @brad, your suggestion is completly possible. In my main file, I could simply create an instance of every single in-game character I have but how many of them will be as the games evolves? Why must I load them all and not the ones someone might have a chance to come across ?

Comment: @brad, I have just noticed your edit. So your suggestion would be to merge all the similar in-game character into differents types and instantiate them according to their types. I like that idea.

Comment: ya something like that.  I'm assuming you'd want to keep a record of these characters somehow.  Instantiating them according to type would allow you to keep a record of the different types and know what they're doing.  Sorry I might not be completely hitting the mark here but I'm still having a bit of difficultly imagining what exactly should happen